# Transformation of a probability distribution - Random variable function of a CDF?

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation

I am trying to wrap my head around a certain topic in my notes, but it seems very confusing.

Let X a continuous random variable whose distribution function $F_X$ is strictly increasing on the possible values of $X$. Then $F_X$ has an inverse function. [Agreed]

Let $U = F_X(X)$, then for $u \in [0,1]$ We wish to find $F_U(u)$:
Since $F_U(u) = P[U\leq u]:$
$$P[U \leq u] = P[F_X(X)\leq u] \; \; \; \; \ \;\;\;(1)$$ 
$$P[U \leq F_X^{-1}(u)]\; \; \; \; \ \;\;\;(2)$$
$$F_X(F_X^{-1}(u))=u\; \; \; \; \ \;\;\; (3)$$

I am probably missing something super obvious, but I am confused by the above 3 steps.

From $(1)$ to $(2)$ - I recognise that we defined $U = F_X(X)$, so that's fine.

But the right hand side of the inequality in $(2)$, how exactly does that make sense?

From $(2)$ to $(3)$,  I think it is saying this is just the CDF of $U<F_X^{-1}(y)$? IS that correct? And the inverse cancels with the $F_X$ to leave $u$.

I.e., $F_U(u) = u$

Any help in understanding would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: If $f$ is an increasing _and_ invertible function, then the relation $f(x) \leq t$ is equivalent to $x \leq f^{-1}(t).$

Comment: This is known as the probability integral transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the right hand side of the inequality in $(2)$, how exactly does that make sense?

It does not.  It should be $X$ rather than $U$.   $F_X(X)\leq u\iff X\leq {F_X}^{-1}(u)$

$$\begin{align}F_U(u) &= \mathsf P(U\leq u) &&\text{by definition of CDF}\\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(F_X(X)\leq u)&&\text{since }U=F_X(X)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leq F_X^{-1}(u)) &\star\\[1ex]&=F_X(F_X^{-1}(u))&&\text{by definition of CDF} \\[1ex] &= u~\mathbf 1_{u\in[0..1]}&&\text{by definition of inversion}\\[3ex]\therefore\qquad U&\sim\mathcal U[0..1]  \end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense.

just to confirm, what exactly does that notation in the last line mean?

with the bolded "1", and subscript $u \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: $\mathsf 1_{u\in[0..1]}$ is a map $u\to\{0,1\}$ with $x\mapsto 0$ if $x\notin[0..1]$ and $x\mapsto 1$ if $x\in[0..1]$.

Comment: It an Indicator Function.  It equals 1 when the indicated event holds, and 0 otherwise. $$\mathbf 1_{u\in[0..1]}=\begin{cases}1 &:& u\in[0..1]\\0 &:& u\notin[0..1]\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks guys! i appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

I think your notes are incorrect and $(2)$ should be:

$$ P[X \le F_X^{-1}(u)],$$

i.e. you passed from $(1)$ to $(2)$ by applying $F_X^{-1}$ to both sides of the inequality in $(1)$. Now this is just $F_X(F_X^{-1}(u))$ (definition of $F_X$), which equals $u$ since $F_X$ is the inverse of $F_X^{-1}$.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform

Comment: Thanks for the clear up! The wiki page makes a lot more sense too.